# checking if a std::vector is of size zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

in vs2010 std::vector.size():

```
return (this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst);
```

and std::vector.empty():

```
return (this->_Myfirst == this->_Mylast);
```

My question is if there is any speed different between this two functions, if you are going to check if a vector has zero elements. 
Minus and equal are almost the same binary operations right, so the speed is the same for both these functions?

Comment: If you are concerned with speed differences, you should first [measure it](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/).

Comment: @BjörnPollex: in this case, I am afraid than measures are useless, as paxdiablo unwittingly demonstrated. For such small things, the best option is to check the compiler output at an intermediate level (AST, IR, assembly) to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I would argue that, if can't measure a significant difference, then you cannot decide between the two options based on performance criteria. This does not mean that measuring is useless.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In any case, one *should* measure before posting such a question.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I disagree. Because measuring is hard. I really like Neil's last punchtape letter (if only he had not stop...) about benchmarks: http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/letter-the-eighth-bedevilling-benchmarks/  The truth is, making a trustworthy benchmark is hard, and I am not confident, *at all*, in the ability of the OP to actually make a good one. And if you cannot trust your measures, then what conclusions can you draw from them ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you are doing this and millions of times a second (and seriously, why *would* you?), it won't make a scrap of difference.

If you're really interested, check it. Set up a loop of a few million times and see how long each takes.

I think you'll find that the difference is negligible.

You would be far better off concentrating on macro-optimisation issues, such as algorithm selection, and optimising this sort of stuff for *readability.*

And, in any case, optimising for readability is a valid approach, and one I usually take unless there are serious performance bottlenecks. In other words, use `empty()` or `!empty()` if you're doing something based on whether or not it's empty. Any other size check (like if there's at least twelve elements in it) should use `size()` (obviously).

As an example of how irrelevant some micro-optimisations can be, here's some C code to ponder:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, k, diff;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            //diff = (i == j);
            diff = (i - j);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile that with default optimisation <sup>(a)</sup>, and run it with the `time` command, I get CPU times of (over five runs), with one of those lines uncommented:

```
diff = (i - j)     diff = (i == j)
==============     ===============
         2.488              2.216
         2.424              2.220
         2.452              2.224
         2.484              2.152
         2.464              2.152
         =====              =====
Avrgs:   2.463              2.193
```

Now that first option is 12% slower but there's one thing you need to understand. Even though it's slower, it still only took two seconds to do this a *billion* times. If you're doing it once, the difference is between 0.000000002463 seconds and 0.000000002193 seconds, not really worth the effort of optimising.

Pick your battles, target your optimisations. You can get *massive* speed improvements with macro-optimisation strategies.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> With `gcc` "insane" optimisation level `-O3`, they both take 0.000 seconds (sometimes 0.004, but rarely - I gather there's a limit to the resolution of the `time` command), making the difference even more irrelevant :-)

Comment: When I compile that, I get: `define i32 @main() nounwind uwtable readnone { ret i32 0 }` with LLVM. That is, the loop is just completely removed since it's doing nothing. Given that `k` is unused and it's not printing anything... is this really the code you used ?

Comment: It is the code I used. Default optimisation level in gcc doesn't optimise it out of existence like LLVM seems to do. There's a good chance `-O3` _did_ optimise the loop out of existence. But don't get too hung up on the code, it's just an example showing that even a 12% difference is rarely relevant when the operations are already blindingly fast.

Comment: `gcc insane` warps the fabric of spacetime

Comment: I confirm inspecting that assembly that in `-O`, `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3` gcc 4.3.2 will fully removes the loop.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I have finally understood where the `12%` could come from: you're not testing what the OP is asking for. `diff = i - j` is far away from `x.size() == 0`. In the latter case, any compiler worth its salt is able to fold the `i - j == 0` into `i == j` (see my answer). And then there is nothing left to measure. Still it's interesting to see how much people *trust* benchmarks, as the amount of upvotes you received show: http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/letter-the-eighth-bedevilling-benchmarks/

Comment: I'm starting to regret putting that code in :-) _Forget_ the code and how it relates to the specific nature of the question. It could measure two totally different things, not even close to what the question asked. The point is: when something only takes 0.000000000000001 seconds, you're wasting your effort in optimising it unless you do it 1000000000000000 times a second.

Comment: @paxdiablo: it's not so much the code itself, rather the whole idea of benchmarking that I am attacking here. The problem is, people *love* benchmark, but nobody really knows how to do it. You probably know more about C that I will ever do, and yet the benchmark you suggest is flawed: what kind of benchmark do you think the OP will come up with ? Chances are he'll measure IOs, or fluctuations in the electromagnetic waves around him, and then that'll convince that one method is definitely faster than the other. **Benchmarks lie**. That's the whole point I am tring to make here :)

Comment: @Matthieu: comparing your comments here with your comments to Björn above, you seem to assume that the only way to measure something is to benchmark it. I expect you know, but I say for the education of others, that the "correct" way to measure something for optimization is to write your application or library, set up a test scenario of a fairly realistic scenario in which this code is hot, and then measure the overall time. If you can't come up with a scenario in which the code is hot, then you don't optimize for performance. If you can't see a speed difference, you don't optimize.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed! However both Björn and paxdiablo proposed benchmarks, and that is what I was reacting to. I fully agree that once you have your application, then *profiling* makes sense.

Comment: @Matthieu: D'oh! I didn't even hover Björn's link, I only read his text. So I thought he was just saying, "measure it", whereas you noticed that he was in fact saying, "benchmark it". So I agree with you entirely: this isn't easily benchmark-able in isolation, and with Clang your observation of the emitted code should halt all further comparison for that compiler anyway.

Answer (score 8):

There are two reasons for using `empty()` over `size()` for checking vector emptyness:

- `std::vector.empty()` *may be faster* than `std::vector.size()` depending on implementations.
- Using `empty()` for checking vector emptyness is more intutive and readable than using `size()`.

---

Reference:
Nicolai M. Josutil's:
*The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference*

which states:

**`size()`**
Returns the actual number of elements of the container.

**`empty()`**
Is a shortcut for checking whether the number of elements is zero (`size()==0`).
However, `empty()` might be implemented more efficiently, so you should use it if
possible.

---

Note though that to be absolutely sure of which one is faster, You will have to profile both for your enviornment.

Comment: +1 for *using `empty()` for checking vector emptyness is more intutive and readable*.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that, but it's true within the closed universe of this one class. Both `empty()` and `clear()` are both verbs and adjectives, so it's essentially arbitrary that in C++ one of them happens to test the container for emptiness, while the other one forces it to become empty. So we're talking a certain specific kind of "intuition" here, that's familiar enough with the standard to read standard functions easily, but unfamiliar enough with the rest of the universe that it has difficulty understanding `size() == 0`. See also `s == ""` vs `s.empty()` vs `s.len() == 0`

Comment: Looking at it another way, `empty()` was more important in the C++03 container interface, where it not only might be faster than `size() == 0`, the latter might not even be O(1) for some containers. I agree with the general principle, "if you want to test whether something is empty, and there's a function that does exactly that, use the function". But I'm not sure that the C++ libraries always follow best practices for readable function names. It should probably have been called `isempty`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: *readability* is a perception based artifact, So there is and always will be room for difference of opinion,While I still consider `empty()` to be more readable than `size()` for checking emptyness, I fully agree with you on C++ Standard libraries not having the best readable names,I also agree `isempty()` would have been a more readable name.

Answer (score 5):

For vector the performance is probably the same. Even if it is not the same it has same Big O complexity and the difference in speed is negligible. So it is probably more convenient to use `empty` if you only want to check that the vector is empty. It describes more accurately what you really want to do.

Another reason to use `empty` is that when you later change the container to `list`, it may have better Big O complexity. Because there are some `std::list` implementations where `size` has linear complexity while empty is always O(1).

Comment: Note: `size` is `O(1)` (guaranteed) for `list` starting from C++11. And so `list` finally obeys all the requirements of a Sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Meyers, in "Effective STL", recommends calling `empty()` instead of checking the size for all containers. The reason he gives is that `empty` is constant-time for all the standard containters, whereas `size` takes linear time in some list implementations.

If you use size and you happen to change your container later, a performance problem could arise.

So, unless checking if the container has no elements is a real bottleneck (measure first, optimize if *there is* a problem), use `empty`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's **stop the fabulations** here:

```
bool empty_by_difference(int* b, int* e) {
  return (e - b) == 0;
}

bool empty_by_equality(int* b, int* e) {
  return e == b;
}
```

Is compiled by Clang 3.0 into the following IR:

```
define zeroext i1 @_Z19empty_by_differencePiS_(i32* %b, i32* %e) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  %1 = icmp eq i32* %e, %b
  ret i1 %1
}

define zeroext i1 @_Z17empty_by_equalityPiS_(i32* %b, i32* %e) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  %1 = icmp eq i32* %e, %b
  ret i1 %1
}
```

You may not know the IR representation, but still I think this will strike home.

So let me speculate than a benchmark is just a loss of my time, and yours.

---

Now, from a semantic point of view, I personally find it clearer to read `if (x.empty())` than to read `if (x.size() == 0)`.

In the latter case:

- my eyes have to work more: distinguishing `==` from `!=` or `<=` or `>=`, ...
- my brain has to work more: remembering than `0` is a kind of sentinel value, very different from any other value such as `1` etc...

Answer (score 1):

If there is a different between empty and size its so small not even a benchmark will see it. Since size is O(1) for list starting from C++11 I think its more readable to write size then empty. But thats just my opinion:)

Answer (score 0):

> Minus and equal are almost the same binary operations right

Indeed, **almost** the same. But AFAIK boolean operators are faster than other operators.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no speed difference. In fact you should see the exact same code generated for both cases.
The compiler should be able to perform the following transformations:

```
if (vec.size() == 0)
// After inlining:
if (_Mylast - _Myfirst == 0)
// Equivalent to:
if (_Mylast == _Myfirst) // Which is the same as empty() after it is inlined
```